# Display good quality image on Android Devices

Tags: c#, android, image-processing

I am working for an android application which display images at run time . Images are stored at server side . The size of images are more than 1 MB . I am looking for a solution by which I can scale down requested image at server side before passing to android devices .  Scaling down image must maintain aspect ration as well .

Please provide me some idea how to achieve this .

Comment: Let the server scale down the image as requested by the client.

Comment: So the purpose of client app is only show the image right ? also is your server application is written in C# ?

Comment: yes my server application is written in c#.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ve had same problem developing an app where I had to download large images whose URLs where stored in a XML feed. What I did is upload the images to Imgur. It has an API where you can simply add a suffix to the image url (in your code) an the image will be scaled by the server. Apple the desired suffix depending on the device dpi and image size. The best way is to measure the total width/height in pixels and request the image resized according to it. More info about the API here https://api.imgur.com/models/image

Comment: Thanks for your reply .  is it free or paid ?

Comment: It is free, I made my own asyc image loader API with it.